# Using one HTML keyboard for two or more text boxes and specifically three in this context

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form with three text boxes and one keyboard, also created using HTML. Anytime I click the buttons of the keyboard to enter data into one of the text boxes, all the three ends up having the same data at once. For clarity, when I click to say, button 7, all the three text boxes end up having the number 7 at once.

I tried the `getElementById` method but it did not work. I also tried setting some of the text boxes to null while entering values into the others, that works neither.

```js
/*text box 1*/
function butns(b) {
  btnN.screen1.value += b;
  document.getElementById('screenNan1').style.display = "";
  document.getElementById('screenNan2').style.display = "";
}

/*text box 2*/
function butns1(c) {
  btnN.screen2.value += c;
  document.getElementById('screenNan').style.display = "";
  document.getElementById('screenNan2').style.display = "";
}

/*text box 3*/
function butns2(d) {
  btnN.screen3.value += d;
  document.getElementById('screenNan').style.display = "";
  document.getElementById('screenNan2').style.display = "";
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" name="btnN" id="chr" class="myfm" action=" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
  <span style="color:white">From number:</span> <br><input id="screenNan1" type="text" name="screen1" value="<?php echo $screen1; ?>"><br><br>

  <span style="color:white">From base:</span> <br><input id="screenNan" type="text" name="screen2" value="<?php echo $screen2; ?>"><br><br>

  <span style="color:white">To base:</span> <br><input id="screenNan" type="text" name="screen3" value="<?php echo $screen3; ?>"><br><br>

  <span style="color:white">Result:</span> <br><input type="text" name="screen" value="<?php echo $converted; ?>"><br><br>

  <input name="conver" type="submit" value="Convert" style="width:50%"><br></br>
  <div class="left">

    <input type="button" value="1" onclick="butns('1'),butns1('1'),butns2('1')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="2" onclick="butns('2'),butns1('2'),butns2('2')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="3" onclick="butns('3'),butns1('3'),butns2('3')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="4" onclick="butns('4'),butns1('4'),butns2('4')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="5" onclick="butns('5'),butns1('5'),butns2('5')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="6" onclick="butns('6'),butns1('6'),butns2('6')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem"> <br><br>


    <input type="button" value="7" onclick="butns('7'),butns1('7'),butns2('7')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="8" onclick="butns('8'),butns1('8'),butns2('8')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="9" onclick="butns('9'),butns1('9'),butns2('9')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="0" onclick="butns('0'),butns1('0'),butns2('0')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="AC" onclick="clear()" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem;background-color:red">
    <input type="button" value="DEL" onclick="" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem;background-color:red"> <br><br>



    <input type="button" value="A" onclick="butns('A'),butns1('A'),butns2('A')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="B" onclick="butns('B'),butns1('B'),butns2('B')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="C" onclick="butns('C'),butns1('C'),butns2('C')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="D" onclick="butns('D'),butns1('D'),butns2('D')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="E" onclick="butns('E'),butns1('E'),butns2('E')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem">
    <input type="button" value="F" onclick="butns('F'),butns1('F'),butns2('F')" style="width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem"> <br><br>
  </div>
</form>
```

Just with ideal keyboard functionality, I want the three text boxes to receive the user input one at a time when the keyboard keys are click instead of filling at a go the three text boxes with the same values.

Comment: It's quite difficult to read the code, but it looks like you have each key having three function calls in every `onclick` attribute, so it makes sense that it would call all three functions when clicked. If you don't want it to type in all three, have a single function and have it only "type" into the field that has focus.

Comment: @HereticMonkey any code syntax suggestions?

Comment: Also, why do you want a keyboard on screen?

Comment: It's ideal for my project :)

Comment: Other than this not working (due to having multiple function calls), there is a lot of code/data duplication. You will also need to handle the input's focus, since when you click on the keyboard, focus will move from the inputs...

Comment: @LeeTaylor send me some codes to get this done. I have tried all I could.

Comment: OK. I've added an answer. It's a work in progress. The top 3 boxes work with the keyboard. I don't know what the fourth one is supposed to do... Please add comments to my answer.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I am sorry but it is never a work in progress but the exact solution to the problem! You nailed it and it's now working in perfect condition. Exactly as I expected! Thanks a lot. But the only issue here now is that the fourth text box, which is supposed to display the result of the converted base is not working

Comment: @AgbesiInnocent You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var $lastFocus = $("#screenNan1");

$("#screenNan1, #screenNan2, #screenNan3").on("focus", function(e)
{
  $lastFocus = $(this);
});

$(".keyboard").on("click", function(e)
{
  var value = $(this).val();
  var current = $lastFocus.val();

  switch(value)
  {
    case "AC":  current = ""; break;
    case "DEL": 
      if(current.length > 0)
        current = current.substring(0, current.length-1);
    break;
    
    default: current += value;   break;
  }
  
  $lastFocus.val(current);
  $lastFocus.focus();
});
```

```css
.keyboard
{
  width:2.5rem;height:2.5rem
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" name="btnN" id="chr" class="myfm">
  <span style="color:white">From number:</span> <br><input id="screenNan1" type="text" name="screen1" value=""><br><br>

  <span style="color:white">From base:</span> <br><input id="screenNan2" type="text" name="screen2" value=""><br><br>

  <span style="color:white">To base:</span> <br><input id="screenNan3" type="text" name="screen3" value=""><br><br>

  <span style="color:white">Result:</span> <br><input type="text" name="screen" value=""><br><br>

  <input name="conver" type="submit" value="Convert" style="width:50%"><br></br>
  <div class="left">

    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="1" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="2" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="3" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="4" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="5" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="6" />
    <br><br>

    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="7" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="8" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="9" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="0" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="AC" style="background-color:red" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="DEL" style="background-color:red" />

    <br><br>

    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="A" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="B" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="C" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="D" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="E" />
    <input class="keyboard" type="button" value="F" />

     <br><br>
  </div>
</form>
```